# bash: ./remoteServer .o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: c, command-line, compilation, executable, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run the c program remoteServer.c. I compiled it using a Makefile. When i try to run it with ./remoteServer.o I get the following error. I read that it could be cause of different architecture but I saw that both were x86-64. I am running ubuntu 18.04.03 on a VM. The code for the make file is after the commands. Also i used chmod 777 on both the .c and .o files.

```
isidoros@isidoros-VirtualBox:~/choice$ ./remoteServer.o

bash: ./remoteServer.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

isidoros@isidoros-VirtualBox:~/choice$ file remoteServer.c

remoteServer.c: C source, ASCII text

isidoros@isidoros-VirtualBox:~/choice$ file remoteServer.o

remoteServer.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped

isidoros@isidoros-VirtualBox:~/choice$ uname -m

x86_64
```

Makefile:

```
OBJS    = remoteServer.o

SOURCE  = remoteServer.c

HEADER  = 

OUT = make

CC   = gcc

FLAGS    = -g -c -Wall

LFLAGS   = 

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS) -o $(OUT) $(LFLAGS)

remoteServer.o: remoteServer.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) remoteServer.c 

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)
```

Comment: You can't run the `.o` file. That is an intermediate object and not the final executable. Your makefile is set up to build an executable called `make`. Not sure whether that is intentional but try looking for and running `./make`.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that [gcc -c compiles source files without linking](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-c.html).

Then, consider that *"Compilation refers to the processing of source code files (.c, .cc, or .cpp) and the creation of an 'object' file. **This step doesn't create anything the user can actually run**. "* [reference](https://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)

Meanwhile: *"Linking refers to the creation of a single executable file from multiple object files."*

So, you probably wanted to link the program, even if it contained a single source file (from your perspective, that might depend on libraries you are including).

I also think that your makefile is trying to name the executable as "make" which might be a problem, since you are probably calling the GNU `make` program to compile you code.